# IntelliJ fails to deploy artifact to Jboss 4.2.3. Failure is instant and without error message

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea

here's a bit of what happens when I click the deploy button to send an artifact to a running server:

> [2013-06-18 01:47:12,436] Artifact Pathways.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
>
> [2013-06-18 01:47:12,509] Artifact Pathways.war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

But nothing shows up in the server log. If I instruct IntelliJ to build the artifact directly to the deployment directory, it's able to do that fine but still unable to deploy from IntelliJ without this error occurring. I'm running OSX 10.8 on a fresh install. I've configured this setup with this codebase numerous times, but I've never quite seen this issue.